# Function pointer, Functor or Lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, function-pointers

I'm relatively new to C++, having spent years with Obj-C, and wondering about how to add what would be closure block in Obj-C, to a C++ class. Here's some pseudo code of what I want to do:

```
class Slider
{
public:
    void onMouseDown()
    {
        if(rightClick or ctlKeyDown)
        {
            if(myFunctionPointer != nil)
            {
                // show popup menu
                myFunctionPointer(this);
            }
        }
    }

    FunctionPointer myFunctionPointer = nil;
};


class Editor
{
public:
    void showPopupMenu(Slider *s)
    {
        // build the popupMenu with information based on the slider
    }

    void init()
    {
        // create a slider and connect the popupMenu function to it
        mySlider = new Slider;
        mySlider->functionPointer = showPopupMenu();
    }

    Slider *mySlider;
};
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get my Slider class to call a function without knowing anything about it.

This shouldn't be that difficult, but I'm interested in doing it the best/proper way. Lambdas and functors look incredibly confusing. Maybe I'm looking for something else. But what?

Comment: It's been a long time that I wrote some C++, but if my memory is still intact, you can write closure in c++ and return it like in javascript/python.

Comment: `std::function` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambdas and functors are one of the most advanced C++ topics. You're better off starting with some fundamentals before, and have a solid understanding of how C++ classes work.

But, since you asked, the C++ equivalent of this should be something like this:

```
class Slider
{
public:
    void onMouseDown()
    {
        if(rightClick or ctlKeyDown)
        {
            if(myFunctionPointer)
            {
                // show popup menu
                myFunctionPointer(this);
            }
        }
    }

    std::function<void (Slider *)> myFunctionPointer=nullptr;
};


class Editor
{
public:
    void showPopupMenu(Slider *s)
    {
        // build the popupMenu with information based on the slider
    }

    void init()
    {
        // create a slider and connect the popupMenu function to it
        mySlider = new Slider;


        mySlider->functionPointer = [this](Slider *)
             {
                   showPopupMenu();
             };

    }

    Slider *mySlider;
};
```

As I said, I think that you're better off focusing your efforts on getting the fundamentals down pat, first, before plunging into these shark-infested waters.

And just to add some additional color: this will compile (the only thing that's missing is the definitions of `rightClick` or `ctlKeyDown`), but it may or may not be right, depending on the scope and the lifetime of the objects involved. It may or may not be necessary to have the lambda capture a `std::shared_ptr`, instead of `this`, depending on how the objects in this application get instantiated. Understanding how C++ objects work would be a necessary prerequisite before dealing with closures and callbacks, of this sort.

Comment: I was about 80% there when you posted this. Thanks. I would have missed the way you declared the actual function. This worked perfectly, although I'm guessing that you meant to use [me](Slider *s) instead of [this](Slider *). Thanks again!

Comment: I actually captured `me` initially, but while pondering the best style, decided to switch back to capturing `this`, but forgot to remove that line.

Comment: Higher order programming may be an advanced *programming* topic -- but for someone who *has* learned it, I strongly disagree with the sentiment that it is something you should avoid doing in C++.

Comment: I do not recall saying that it should be avoided permanently.

Answer (score 7):

When it comes to treating function as objects, your basic options are: function pointer, functor/lambda, std::function. I am going to assume that you can find out their syntax and will focus on their difference.

A function pointer should be used when there is no need for a closure. This applies when the procedure you want to call is stateless or has a global state, and you have all parameters in the scope.

A functor should be used when you need to create a closure. Since functors are objects, you can maintain an internal state and pass parameters inside the closure.

A lambda is essentially a functor, without an explicit typename. The capture list of a lambda is its member if it were implemented as a functor instead. Note that you can overload `operator()` for a functor but not a lambda.

The problem with functor/lambdas is that each of their definition has a different type, and can be ill-suited in function signature/class member types. std::function resolves the problem by being able to accept functor/lambda/function pointer and convert them to a uniform type of std::function. You pay a (often small) price for this flexibility in the form of performance though.

Comment: I think I disagree with your advice about function pointers -- what you describe is a *necessary* condition for their use, but is not a *sufficient* condition. Using a function pointer instead of `std::function` is an *optimization*, and probably a premature one.

Comment: @hurkyl As an aside, sufficient reasons for using a function pointer over a std function include include need for nothrow copy/construct, constexpr evaluation of value or template non-type argument, standard layout and other pod requirements, guarantee of statelessness, etc.  Did I miss any important ones you know of?

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways to achieve what you're looking for. 
Here's a way, avoiding function pointers.

I didn't correct some other obvious mistakes, like the memory leak that arises from calling`new` and never deleting the object. 
Best practice in this case would be using a `std::unique_ptr`

```
class Slider
{
public:

    Slider(Editor& e)
  : _e(e)
  { }
    void onMouseDown()
    {
        if(rightClick or ctlKeyDown)
        {
            _e.showPopupMenu(this);
        }
    }

    Editor& _e;
};


class Editor
{
public:
    void showPopupMenu(Slider *s)
    {
        // build the popupMenu with information based on the slider
    }

    void init()
    {
        // create a slider and connect the popupMenu function to it
        mySlider = new Slider(*this);
    }

    Slider* mySlider;
};
```

Here's another solution moving a functor directly in the constructor, however using templates.

```
template <typename Handler>
class Slider
{
public:

        Slider(Handler&& h)
        : _h(std::move(h))
        { }

    void onMouseDown()
    {
        if(rightClick or ctlKeyDown)
        {
           // show popup menu
           _h(this);
        }
    }

        Handler _h;
};


class Editor
{
public:
    void showPopupMenu(Slider *s)
    {
        // build the popupMenu with information based on the slider
    }

    void init()
    {
        // create a slider and connect the popupMenu function to it
        mySlider = new Slider([this](Slider* s){ showPopupMenu(s); });
    }

    Slider *mySlider;
};
```

You could also use a `std::function` instead, as shows on another answer

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a way that Slider wouldn't have to know anything about Editor.

Comment: you're really better off having an interface (contract) of some kind. Often just passing function pointers/`std::function` wrappers is not the best solution and it will result in maintenance nightmares.

Comment: I think these are terrible solutions for the use case in the OP; I did not downvote, however, since the approaches can sometimes be reasonable for other problems.

Comment: I personally find quite useful to template these kind of things, of course not as a general rule. In generic code it helps a lot and ti means you can pass a functor, a lambda, a function pointer and everything would still work.

Comment: How does `_h(this)` compile? I don't see any template given in the `Slider *mySlider` declaration. Is the compiler able to infer everything without a warning?